# How to pass json return values to new screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I tried to pass json data to another screen which is not working.

How can I pass the value and print it in the second screen?

```
var response = await http.post(url, body: json.encode(data));

    // Getting Server response into variable.
    var message = json.decode(response.body);

    String message1 = message['message'];
    String userid = message['userid'];

    Navigator.push(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen(name: userid)));
```

Answer (score 0):

On the first screen, you need to use pushNamed and then enter the variables you wish to pass to the next screen as 'arguments'.

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(SecondScreen.routeName, arguments: userid));
```

To use pushNamed, it is good practice to create a routeName static property in the class and add the screen to the `routes:` table in main.dart.

On the second screen, you need to accept the data and save it in a variable with which you can then print it.

This is the syntax to get the data on the second screen.

```
ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as `data type`. or String in your case.
```